# Concatenate single elements in python list

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, list

I have a nested list like this:

```
lst =[['Start двигаться', 'другая сторона света', 'надолго скоро'],
      ['Start двигаться', 'другая сторона света', 'чтобы посмотреть'],
      ['Start двигаться', 'новая планета'],
      ['Start двигаться', 'сторона признание', 'суверенитет израильский'],
      ['Start двигаться', 'сторона признание', 'высот', 'на'],
      ['Start двигаться', 'сторона признание', 'высот', 'оккупировать'],
      ['Start двигаться', 'сторона признание', 'высот', 'Голанский'],
      ['Start двигаться', 'сторона признание', 'и']]
```

I need to check if last element is single word, and if it is, concatenate it with previous element.
Desired output:

```
    [['Start двигаться', 'другая сторона света', 'надолго скоро'], 
     ['Start двигаться', 'другая сторона света', 'чтобы посмотреть'],
     ['Start двигаться', 'новая планета'],
     ['Start двигаться', 'сторона признание', 'суверенитет израильский'],
     ['Start двигаться', 'сторона признание', 'высот на'],
     ['Start двигаться', 'сторона признание', 'высот оккупировать'],
     ['Start двигаться', 'сторона признание', 'высот Голанский'],
     ['Start двигаться', 'сторона признание и']]
```

So far I thought about checking last element for whitespace:

```
for i in lst:
    for j in i:
        if " " not in j[-1]:
            do smth
```

But I'm not sure this is the right way. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right track, but you don't need a 2nd loop:

```
for sublist in lst:
    if ' ' not in sublist[-1]:
        # merge the last two elements
        text = '{} {}'.format(sublist[-2], sublist.pop())
        sublist[-1] = text

# result:
# [['Start двигаться', 'другая сторона света', 'надолго скоро'],
#  ['Start двигаться', 'другая сторона света', 'чтобы посмотреть'],
#  ['Start двигаться', 'новая планета'],
#  ['Start двигаться', 'сторона признание', 'суверенитет израильский'],
#  ['Start двигаться', 'сторона признание', 'высот на'],
#  ['Start двигаться', 'сторона признание', 'высот оккупировать'],
#  ['Start двигаться', 'сторона признание', 'высот Голанский'],
#  ['Start двигаться', 'сторона признание и']]
```

Comment: Thanks! Easier, then I thought=)

Answer (score 1):

You can use split function to check if its a single word or not. If you use the split function you can even check if there is string with tabs(\t) as well.

```
for ele in lst:
    if len(ele[-1].split())==1:
        new = ele[-2]+" "+ele[-1]
        del ele[-2:]
        ele.append(new)
```

Answer (score 0):

One way may be to try with `list comprehension` as below:

```
[item[:-2]+ [' '.join(item[-2:])] 
                          if len(item[-1].split()) == 1 else item for item in lst ]
```

It looks for the last item in the inner list, calls `split` and checks length. If length is 1 then, it takes rest of element except last 2 and joins last to the list.

Comment: Congratulations, you solved a trivial problem with unreadable code.